# arduino program runs only at start up

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

My arduino program runs only when on start up or when i press the reset button, i dont know the problem as i am a new bee into this. Please need help.

i have some constants here for the remote control, and i am just trying to replicate what i am sending through the arduino ir led, every thing works fine except that the program runs only once.

```
    #include <IRremote.h>       // use the library 


  #define PanasonicAddress      0x4004     // Panasonic address (Pre data) 
  #define PanasonicPower        0x100BCBD  // Panasonic Power button
  #define PanasonicZero        0x1009899  // Panasonic button
  #define PanasonicOne        0x1000809  // Panasonic button
  #define PanasonicTwo        0x1008889  // Panasonic button
  #define PanasonicThree        0x1004849  // Panasonic button
  #define PanasonicFour        0x100C8C9  // Panasonic button
  #define PanasonicFive        0x1002829  // Panasonic button
  #define PanasonicSix        0x100A8A9  // Panasonic button
  #define PanasonicSeven        0x1006869  // Panasonic button
  #define PanasonicEight        0x100E8E9  // Panasonic button
  #define PanasonicNine        0x1001819  // Panasonic button

  #define PMute        0x1004C4D
  #define PCPlus        0x1002C2D
  #define PCMinus        0x100ACAD
  #define PVMinus        0x1008485
  #define PVPlus        0x1000405
  #define PRTune        0x100ECED
  #define JVCPower      0xC5E8

    int receiverpin = 15; // pin 1 of IR receiver to Arduino digital pin 15 
    IRsend irsend;
    IRrecv irrecv(receiverpin); // create instance of irrecv
    decode_results results; 


  void setup()
  {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  irrecv.enableIRIn();         // start the IR receiver
 // pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  for (int z = 11 ; z < 14 ; z++) // set up digital pins 
  {
    pinMode(z, OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // have we received an IR signal?
  {
    translateIR();
  for (int z = 0 ; z < 2 ; z++) // ignore the repeated codes
    {
      irrecv.resume(); // receive the next value
    }
  }
}


  void translateIR() 
  // takes action based on IR code received
  // uses Sony IR codes
  {
    switch(results.value)
  {
     case PanasonicFour:  pinOnTriple(1, 0, 0); 
     irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PanasonicFour); // This should turn your TV on and off
     break; // 2

    case PanasonicTwo:  pinOnTriple(0, 1, 0); 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PanasonicTwo); 
    break; // 3


    case PanasonicFive:  pinOnTriple(HIGH, LOW, HIGH); 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PanasonicFive); 
    break; // 5

    case PanasonicSix:  pinOnTriple(HIGH, HIGH, LOW); 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PanasonicSix); 
    break; // 6

    case PanasonicSeven:  pinOnTriple(HIGH, HIGH, HIGH); 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PanasonicSeven); 
    break; // 7

    case PanasonicZero:  pinOnTriple(LOW, LOW, LOW); 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PanasonicZero); 
    break; // 8

    case PanasonicOne:  pinOnTriple(LOW, LOW, HIGH); 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PanasonicOne); 
    break; // 9

    case PanasonicThree:  pinOnTriple(LOW, HIGH, HIGH); 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PanasonicThree); 
    break; // 10

   case 0x100BCBD:  pinOnTriple(LOW, LOW, LOW); 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PanasonicPower); // This should turn your TV on and off
     irsend.sendJVC(JVCPower, 16,0); // hex value, 16 bits, no repeat
      delay(50); // see http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/jvc.php for information
      irsend.sendJVC(JVCPower, 16,1); // hex value, 16 bits, repeat
      delay(50);
    break;

    case 0x1004C4D:  
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PMute);
    break; // 11         
    case 0x1002C2D: 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PCPlus); 
    break; // 11         
    case 0x100ACAD:   
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PCMinus); 
    break; // 11
    case 0x1008485: 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PVMinus); 
    break; // 11         
    case 0x1000405: 
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PVPlus); 
    break; // 11
    case 0x100ECED:  
    irsend.sendPanasonic(PanasonicAddress,PRTune); 
    break; // 11
}
}


void pinOnTriple(int pin, int pino, int pini) // turns on digital pins for 1 second
{
  digitalWrite(11, pin);
  digitalWrite(12, pino);
  digitalWrite(13, pini);
  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(11, 0);
  digitalWrite(12, 0);
  digitalWrite(13, 0);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just check for receiving the repeat codes (0xFFFFFF) and just ignore this code. And just issue the resume command just once. You may be accidently skipping the valid codes.

Also, you  need to issue a resume after  transmitting IR (as tx disables rx).

This last one is probably the issue for you.

Hope it helps

### may be worth putting in a delay before re-tx as the tx may overlap the repeat codes

For anyone interested in IR protocols - we have just launched a project for AnalysIR - IR Decoder &  Analyzer GUI (Arduino & Raspberry Pi). Currently we support 17 IR protocols and are looking for more to add as part of the campaign. Suggestions Welcome!

If the project is successful, we hope to add support for Raspberry Pi !

You can find out more and support the Project by visiting http://igg.me/at/AnalysIR/x/3752156 or Screenshot via www.AnalysIR.com